# Using sed to unlock fields in a pdf

Tags: sed

At my job we regularly unlock the fields of pdf files in order to edit them using this sed script in a .bat file:

```
type %1 | sed -E 's/(.*\/T\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\).*)\/Ff 1(\/?.*)/\1\/Ff 0\2/' |  sed      -E 's/(.*\/T\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\).*)\/Ff 4097(\/?.*)/\1\/Ff 4096\2/'>"%~n1.UNLOCKED%~x1"
```

But now it doesn't work and we have been working on it for 4 days now and are completely stumped. Unfortunately, the guy who wrote it no longer works here and did not leave good documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming It doesn't work on newer files, and still does on the old ones. Have you looked at the properties of those newer files, PDF version numbers etc. I suspect the PDF generator is now using compression/encryption etc that no longer allows you to simple match.

Comment: Try this also: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4345/remove-security-limitations-from-pdf-documents-using-ghostscript